# android-way to prevent NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: android, eclipse, nosuchmethoderror

I was trying to use a method that requires api level 14 while I have min api level set to 8. Eclipse shouldn't even let me compile if I don't take care of that part (eg.`@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)`), but Eclipse didn't complain this time and let me compile successfully. During runtime, I got NoSuchMethodError with some older devices.

I copied exact same code to another new machine with fresh Eclipse, and Eclipse complained this time....Why is that? Eclipse doesn't seem to be reliable... Is there any other 3rd party application that I can use to check if all methods used are equal or below the min api level? or if there's anyway that I can force Eclipse to check? There's really no way for me to check the api level for every single method I use.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13) {
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            width = size.x;

        } else
            width = display.getWidth();
```

Comment: if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13) checks your version. you can check on what version the user have and then use the method you want.

Comment: I guess my question wasn't clear enough. I know how to check user's sdk version. my question is if you take `if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13)` off, eclipse should give an error like `Call requires API level 14 (current min is 8)` and stop you from compiling the app.

Comment: for some reason, eclipse isn't very reliable on this. I can still compile on my old machine...